# Scaling of delimiters and \widetilde does not work with Libertinus

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, unicode-math, libertinus

I’m using XeLaTeX and I recently started using the Libertinus font family.
I ran into the problem that scaling of delimiters does not always seem to work.
As an example, take the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) \quad
  \left[ \frac{a}{b} \right] \quad
  \left\langle \frac{a}{b} \right\rangle \quad
  \left. \frac{a}{b} \middle/ \frac{c}{d} \right. \quad
  \left. \frac{a}{b} \middle\backslash \frac{c}{d} \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output:

[image: output for different delimiters]

While the scaling works in the first two cases, the other cases are unaffected.

On a similar note, `\widetilde` does not seem to scale with the length of its argument while `\widehat` does.
I suspect these problem are somehow related, but I’m not sure of it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}

\[
  \widetilde{abcdefg} \quad \widehat{abcdefg}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: widehat works while widetilde does not]

I’ve been trying to figure out where this problem comes from, but I had no success so far.
I first suspected that the Libertinus Math font is missing some features, but especilly the difference between `\widetilde` and `\widehat` seems too strange for that (surely, if one of them is supported then the other should be too).

I would like to know how to make the delimiters and widetilde scale appropriately, preferably without changing the font.

Comment: I can confirm same in texlive 2017 possibly a font issue but I don't feel up to trying to understand the font tables in fontforge tonight someone may answer.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the fonts to me, so I would suggest to report it: https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus

Comment: Confirmed also with the recent update of Libertinus (on TL 2017)

Comment: I see similar issues with \widehat and \widetilde under LuaLaTeX when using the Libertinus Math font.  The problem is not present for  \widehat under XeLaTeX but remains for \widetilde.

Comment: This may be fixed in the latest version of the font, see [issue 102](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus/issues/102).

Comment: Any news? Is the font issue fixed with the latest version(see Calebs comment)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has [been fixed](https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus/issues/102) and the MWE now (in the current version 6.6) produces the following output :

[image: delimiters work]
[image: widetilde works]