# Libertinus, widetilde and amssymb

Tags: amssymb, libertinus

I am having trouble with typsetting `\widetilde` using `libertinus` when using `amssymb`. The code compiles when `amssymb` is not used, but produces a g looking tilde (not wide). There is no difference in the `widetilde` or `tilde` Though [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370282/scaling-of-delimiters-and-widetilde-does-not-work-with-libertinus) question suggests that it has been resolved with the update, I could not get the same results. I am on TL2020 and using XeLaTeX to compile. When `amssymb` is used instead of the small tilde, something else appears.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}

% these are repeated symbols hence the relax
\let\eth\relax
\let\digamma\relax
\let\backepsilon\relax

\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
The operator $\widetilde{\hat{L}}$ is said to be the \emph{transpose} of the operator
$\hat{L}$ if the following condition is satisfied:

$\widetilde{\hat{L}}$ widetilde

$\tilde{\hat{L}}$ tilde

\end{document}
```

[image: widetilde and tilde]

[image: result without <code>amssymb</code>]
[image: result with <code>amssymb</code>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to load `amssymb`, actually. If you load it after `libertinus` the output is wrong, if you load it earlier, then `amssymb` does actually nothing at all.

The fact is that `libertinus` loads `unicode-math` with the Libertinus Math font.

If you don't like the output of the wide tilde, which is actually incorrect, use `newtxmath` with the `libertine` option and pass `libertinus` the `nomath` option.

I also increased the baselineskip so the double accent doesn't clash with the previous line, but you should be aware that double accents are dangerous under this respect.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[nomath]{libertinus}

\linespread{1.2}

\begin{document}
The operator $\widetilde{\hat{L}}$ is said to be the \emph{transpose} of the operator
$\hat{L}$ if the following condition is satisfied:

$\widetilde{\hat{L}}$ widetilde

$\tilde{\hat{L}}$ tilde

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output with just `\usepackage{libertinus}`

[image]

Comment: I had included in the MWE. `amssymb` as removing it seemed to solve the problem (at least no weird symbol). Is `amssymb` a deprecated pacakge now - I cannot seem to find anything on CTAN. Does `amsmath` need to be loaded before the font packages? The actual document has wider linespacing, since this was MWE I did not include it.